# How can i delete specific item from LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

There is a lot of value in my local store and I want to delete some of them. When I click on the dynamic card I created, it should be deleted both normally and locally. I can normally delete it but I can not delete it from local.

The local storage event is very confusing and does not have a lot of explanatory resources. at least i could not find it. Thank you for your help already.

[This is codepen](https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/RBgeRR)

```js
$('#field').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#field').val() === '') return false;

        let comment = {
            card: $('#field').val(),
            id: generateGUID()
        };
        $('#field').val('')
        var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
        store.push(comment);
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(store));
        $(this).val('');
        displayComment(comment);
    }
});

function displayComment(comment) {
    var html = $(`<div class="card" data-id="${comment.id}"><h5>${comment.card}</h5></div>`);
    $('.yorum').append(html);

    $('.yorum').find(html).click(function () {
        $(html).remove();
    });

}


var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
store.forEach(displayComment);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `localStorage.removeItem('ITEM_NAME')` method of the `localStorage` object.

Here is an example of creation, getting and removing items in the `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('aaa','1231')  //undefined
localStorage.getItem('aaa')         //"1231"
localStorage.removeItem('aaa')      //undefined
localStorage.getItem('aaa')         //null
```

Here is example of code for your case:

```
function displayComment(comment) {
    var html = $(`<div class="card" data-id="${comment.id}"><h5>${comment.card}</h5></div>`);
    $('.yorum').append(html);

    $('.yorum').find(html).click(function () {
        $(html).remove();
        var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
          {
            if(arr[i].id=this.getAttribute('data-id'))
            {
              arr.splice(i,1);
              break;
            }
          }
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(arr));
    });

}
```

Comment: its will be delete everything. we cant do this.

Comment: @ÖmerDoğan what do you mean by saying everything? it will delete only item with the specific key in the localStorage

Comment: @ÖmerDoğan in your implementation you will have to get the array with `localStorage.getItem()`, remove the `todo` with specified `ID` from it and write new array with `localStorage.setItem();` on the same `todo` key.

Comment: yes it was descriptive indeed but local storage really complex. i cant understand. :(

Comment: Yes. This time happened and i think its was nice way to this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your click handler you also have to get your parsed local store value then call splice(index, 1) passing the entry number as "index".

Something like...

```js
$('#field').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#field').val() === '') return false;

        let comment = {
            card: $('#field').val(),
            id: generateGUID()
        };
        $('#field').val('')
        var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
        store.push(comment);
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(store));
        $(this).val('');
        displayComment(comment, store.length-1);
    }
});

function displayComment(comment, index) {
    var html = $(`<div class="card" data-id="${comment.id}"><h5>${comment.card}</h5></div>`);
    $('.yorum').append(html);

    $('.yorum').find(html).click(function () {
        $(html).remove();
        var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
        store.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(store));
    });

}


var store = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
store.forEach(displayComment);
```

Comment: Yess! this is what i want dude. But not useful. it is not working properly. some cards made an error.

Comment: Yes. I think using an object instead of an array for your storage would make it work better. Use comment.id as the key then “delete storage[comment.id]” in your click handler instead of splice.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

Replace key as per requirement

Comment: if im do this will be delete every value.

Comment: No it will remove specific key

Comment: but my case all value in one array. if i use this method everything will be delete.

Comment: so can you give the data structure of your array

Comment: than please use like localStorage.removeItem(yourArray['speciic_key']);

Answer (score 0):

All answers are well. How ever you also can do like this:

```
localStorage[key] = undefined;
```

Since localstorage is a key-value object